# Access 2013 - query with ConcatRelated containing 50000 entries taking forever

Tags: ms-access

I have a sql query I have below to convert a table with 3 columns containing 600000 entries to 50000 entries by concatenating similar entries

```
SELECT Users, ConcatRelated("Locations", "Report", "Users = '" & 
Report.Users & "' AND Roles = '" & Report.Roles & "'") AS NewLocation, Roles
FROM Report
GROUP BY Users, Roles;
```

The query generates but now I wanted to import it as a table into another access file.
I tried to export as an excel file but even after 2 hours it kept going.
I tried to convert it into a table and import that table to an excel or access file by using the

```
INTO NewTable
```

in above query but that is also taking  a long time and shows no sign of completion.

ConcatRelated is a function from [HERE](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)

Any help would be really great!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query cannot be correct, it must be `GROUP BY Users, Roles`?

Comment: If the above is true, you should first do the grouping (INSERT INTO temp table), then run ConcatRelated on the result.

Comment: when using group by clause, the select will have either one of the aggregate functions like sum, min, max, avg, first, last OR the fields in group by clause. Your query will give error since you are using two fields in select without any aggregate function i.e. Users, NewLocation. if you want to have group by do correct for field names or make another query based this result. I do not see any problem in inserting 50k records to new table if the query is corrected.

Comment: @Andre sorry the group by is "GROUP BY Users, Roles" . Moreover the query output which I got, I ran export to excel and left it run overnight. After about approx 6 hours it generated the excel file with the query output. It this the normal speed?

Comment: Wow, 6 hours, awesome. :-) The GROUP BY is killing you, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConcatRelated` is not a cheap function. It has to open and loop a recordset for each call.

Currently you call it for **every** record in the `Report` table, but you need to do it only once per User & Role.

So: first do the grouping with INSERT or SELECT INTO a temp table:

```
SELECT Users, Roles
INTO TempUsersRoles
FROM Report
GROUP BY Users, Roles
```

And then `ConcatRelated` based on the records in the temp table:

```
SELECT Users, 
    ConcatRelated("Locations", "Report", 
        "Users = '" & t.Users & "' AND Roles = '" & t.Roles & "'") AS NewLocation, 
    Roles
FROM TempUsersRoles AS t
```

It will probably still run some time (depending on how many distinct users+roles there are), but should be much better than before.

(Edit: you told us, 50k vs. 600k, so it should run at least 12 times faster.)

Adding an **index** on Users+Roles in `Report` might help to make the function faster.
Users+Roles should also be the primary key in `TempUsersRoles` (not sure if it makes a difference).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 9 hours in a second!