# MS Access - Speed Issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a pretty slow query:

```
SELECT ticketnumber, stateactual, adj, 
  ConcatRelated("utilityname","IntTable","ticketnumber = """ & ticketnumber   & """" & " AND " & "stateactual = """ & stateactual & """") AS utilities, 
  ConcatRelated("startupcustomer","IntTable","ticketnumber = """ & ticketnumber   & """" & " AND " & "stateactual = """ & stateactual & """") as startdates
INTO tixconcat
FROM IntTable
WHERE stateactual = "MT"
GROUP BY ticketnumber, stateactual, adj;
```

I used this gent's concatrelated query:

http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

This works perfectly - but it's really slow.  Like, one record a second.  I'm trying to run this on 1.1 million records and I really need it done sometime before the next election.  Any ideas?

I've already compacted and repaired the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Denormalizing data does have its drawbacks. Is your data on local computer or are you accessing over network to server? It might be a little faster on local data but I doubt it will be enough.

Comment: ConcatRelated looks like a UDF (user-defined function) which is the primary cause of your speed issues.  UDFs are really flexible ways of transforming data, but using them in a query with hundreds of thousands or millions of rows will always be slow.

Comment: Do the [ticketnumber] and [stateactual] fields have indexes in the [IntTable] table?

Comment: create mysql db on your machine, push all data to mysql, use access as front-end. easy, fast and robust!

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34691645/3820271 (maybe you already did). First run the GROUP BY into a temp table, then run the expensive `ConcatRelated` on the smaller result.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that is taking time is the ConcatRelated function. It's opening up a table, searching it, giving a result, and then closing the table twice per row. If you want to make this process fast, you need to use SQL instead of user-defined functions to denormalize your data.

To concatenate your fields, this is the process I use to make it fast.

**Step 1**
Use a crosstab query to get the fields you want to concatenate on 1 row. Use your foreign keys as row headings, and the thing you want to concatenate as both column heading and value

**Step 2**
Concatenate the columns you want to concatenate from the crosstab query

**Step 3** Make your final query, and join the query/result of the query from step 2

You will need to use 5 queries (step 1 and 2 once per concatenated field), but it will still be WAY faster than what you are doing now. Note that you can already filter in step 1.

The result might be slightly different, since ConcatRelated can concat the same value twice, and my approach won't

Comment: I follow.  I have 1100 foreign keys.  No row in the final product will have more than a dozen.  Do you think it will work with that many columns?  I may have to rethink my approach entirely.

Answer (score 1):

One person in the comments suggesting indexing the fields.  That worked - ran the whole query in an hour :)

Answer (score 0):

As others noted it is not such much calling the function for each row (that is costly). However, loading the sql string, loading the query processor, checking the SQL syntax and THEN JET/ACE has to build a query plan, and THEN open the table and THEN execute the query is where the cost is.

What I would suggest by-passing the query processor, and opening the table directly “once” at the start of the query. And this thus means using the seek() command as it will hit the index directly and by-pass sql.

This code should run about 1000 times faster:

```
Public Function MyCon(vPK As Variant) As String

  Static rst  As DAO.Recordset
  Static db   As DAO.Database
  Dim strV    As String
  Dim bolF    As Boolean
  'Stop
  If rst Is Nothing Then
     Set db = CurrentDb
     Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblChild")
  End If

  With rst
     .Index = "main_id"
     .MoveFirst
     .Seek "=", vPK

     bolF = Not (.NoMatch)
     Do While bolF
        If MyCon <> "" Then MyCon = MyCon & ","
        MyCon = MyCon & rst!InvoiceNumber
       .MoveNext
       If .EOF = True Then
          bolF = False
       Else
          bolF = rst!main_id = vPK
       End If
     Loop
  End With


End Function
```

NOTE in above the use of "static" - this means the variable KEEPS its value - we thus only open the table one time.